# Express. Parse JSON from URL

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to do get request and get data from URL.
I use an Express framework. Before I've used only Node JS and all was OK. But people from stack recommend me to use express.

So, I try to run app and render data from url to my `ejs` page.
But I got `Cannot GET /`

Please, can you help me with my mistake?

My app.js code:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var http = require('http');
    var path = require('path');
    var config = require('config');
    var log = require('libs/log')(module);
    var request = require('request');

    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var url = 'http://public.api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders?offset=2018-01-05T21:02:46.167030+02:00';
    var app = express();
    app.set('port', config.get('port'));

    app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'templates'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/', router);

    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        request('http://public.api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders?offset=2018-01-05T21:02:46.167030+02:00', function (err, response, body) {
            if (err || response.statusCode !== 200) {
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            res.render('index', { title : 'Main page', news : JSON.parse(body), some: '<b>Hello</b>' });
        });
    });

    // app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    //     res.render("index", {
    //         body: '<b>Hello</b>'
    //     });
    // });

    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
       if(app.get('env') == 'development') {
         var errorHandler = express.errorHandler();
         errorHandler(err, req, res, next);
       } else {
         res.send(500);
       }

    });


    http.createServer(app).listen(config.get('port'), function() {
        log.info('Express server listening on port ' + config.get('port'));
    });


    module.exports = app;
```

And my small ejs file:

```
<%-news%>
<%-some%>
```

[image]

On the screenshot is the JSON which I want to display on the page.

Comment: Your app needs to use the router. 

Try calling app.use('/', router)

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare, thanks, I changed code in question because I can't see data in view..

Comment: In your code, you are using request module. You missed to call the get method there. Modify it to "request.get(url" instead of "request(url". It will work. All the best!!!

Comment: @ganka, yes, thanks, but my question is: how render my data from url to page? because now I got only [object Object]. sorry

Comment: Can you post an example of what the JSON you’re receiving looks like?

Comment: Are you looking for req.query?  I'm not sure I understand the question otherwise.

Comment: @Paul, question edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`news` contains three props, `next_page`, `data`, and `prev_page`. If you want to access the contents of `data` you will need to loop through it as it is an `array`:

```
<% if (news.data) { %>
  <% news.data.forEach(function(obj){ %>
    <span><%= obj.id %></span>
  <% }); %>
<% } %>
```

It can be a little tricky sometimes to keep track of `ejs` syntax. There are a lot of `npm` modules that you can check out if the standard error messages are hard to read.

Comment: yes, but I still get only [object Object]. I don't know what I did incorrectly to display json content in pretty good view.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks a lot! But I can render all text without stringify and without parse method in app.js..
if you can, one more question..
how can I render only ID for example?

If I write in ejs file news.id I get anything.

Comment: Sure! I think I know what you are after. Check new answer.

Comment: you are the best! thanks for the description. I finally understood

Comment: No worries! Glad it helped.